# Does stdcall use SSE registers? And does he restore them?

Tags: winapi, stdcall

I am interested in whether stdcall uses SSE registers on x86, and if so, will it restore them, like ESI, EDI, EBP, EBX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

As you mentioned, [the Windows x86-32 ABI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions) specifies that `EAX`, `EDX`, and `ECX` are available as "scratch" registers inside of the function (clobbered); all of the other general-purpose integer registers are preserved (i.e., `EBX`, `ESI`, `EDI`, `EBP`, and `EIP`). This doesn't apply to SSE registers; only to general-purpose integer registers. All of the SSE registers are considered to be clobbered.